# Laptop keyboard and touchpad disabled on startup

Tags: boot

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my Toshiba Satellite L775D laptop.  14.04 is the only operating system installed.  I am new to Linux and only barely scratching the surface of doing things in terminal.

When I boot my laptop keyboard and touchpad are disabled (99.99% of the time) if I do nothing.  The only direct effect I can have is to keep pressing the "numlock" key during boot when I notice the "numlock" light goes off.  If I do this then I have a 95% chance of the keyboard and touchpad working when I am in the operating system.  I am able to use my wireless mouse regardless.

I have not seen any messages during boot.  Previously I have tried playing with input method settings and utilities as well as language support settings.  This same problem exists with the 12.... and 13... versions of ubuntu. With everything I have tried (from looking at other posts/suggestions) it seems I can have only a temporary effect.

Please help me find a permanent solution to this problem. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my Toshiba L775D laptop. The reason is a non-standard (or let's say exotic) connection of the keyboard and touchpad to the internal PS/2 interface of the laptop. Adding **atkbd.reset** and **i8042.nomux** at the end your grub command line (after **nosplash quiet**) will help you get rid of the problem. This solution was also posted in the MINT forums. See the last post in http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=152185