# No touchpad and keyboard on Toshiba Sattelite at start

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, suspend, fglrx, toshiba-satellite

I have a big problem because I can't log in to Ubuntu on my computer, because when I see the login screen, nothing works.

Originally, I solved the problem using [this soplution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465136/laptop-keyboard-and-touchpad-disabled-on-startup) (I pressed <kbd>NumLock</kbd> when the computer starts and after that I added `atkbd.reset` and `i8042.nomux` at the end of my grub command line).

It worked and the problem was solved, but I had another one, when I suspended the laptop and woke it up it had a black screen every time. I solved it by installing the "fglrx" proprietary package.

After I solved the problem with suspend, I rebooted my computer and the first problem returned: when I start Ubuntu I have the login screen but the touchpad nor keyboard work any more (even if I press <kbd>NumLock</kbd> during start).

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Is the atkbd.reset and i8042.nomux still in your grub config?  (Use an external keyboard to check)

Comment: Yes, now I have this line in grub config GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash atkbd.reset i8042.nomux"

Comment: Sorry, cannot help you further then.  I've edited your answer to make it more clear, but that's the maximum I can do... :-(

Comment: Thank You for Your help. I discovered one thing. When I have a USB Stick conected to my computer during startup, then the problem does not occur.

Comment: Huh???  OK...  Could you post `tail /var/log/{kern.log,dmesg,syslog}` when an USB has been inserted and when not?  Post both to paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Hmm i can not boot linux, without inserted USB, because i don't have external keyboard. Is it ok if i post only tail var/log with USB?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "USB stick".  No worries about keyboard and mouse. so start with the USB stick inserted, do the `tail /var/log/{kern.log,dmesg,syslog}`, then remove the USB stick.